# Prove a property of the divisor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $q$ be an odd composite integer and $\sigma(q)$  the sum of the positive divisors of $q$. For what $q$ is it true that $$(\sigma(q)-q) \mid (q-1) \;?$$ If $q$ is prime, it is clear that it is true.
Is it only true for all primes $q$? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried for powers of primes?

Comment: yes, in fact q must be deficient and not almost perfect.

Comment: $q$ is odd composite.

Comment: Have a look at http://oeis.org/A059046

Comment: thanks a lot @ Matthew Conroy...

Comment: Note q and $\sigma(q)$ would have to be coprime. if qA -($\sigma(q)$)(B) = 1 with A=B+1 then the above divisibility equation would work.

Comment: If ($\sigma(q)$)M - qM = (q - 1) for some integer M , then ($\sigma(q)$)M - q ( M + 1) = - 1 therefore $\sigma(q)$ and q are relatively prime.