# Prove a property of the divisor function (Part 2)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Further to this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679489), I would like to pose a follow-up inquiry:

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(\sigma(n) - n) \mid (n - 1)$, does it follow that $n$ and $\sigma(n)$ would have to be coprime, so that $n$ is a solitary number (by Greening's Theorem)?

[user128932](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/128932) commented in the linked MSE question that:

> > If $nA - \sigma(n)B = 1$ with $A = B + 1$, then the above divisibility relation would work.

Substituting $A = B + 1$, I get:

$$n(B + 1) - \sigma(n)B = 1$$

so that

$$nB + n - \sigma(n)B = 1.$$

Consequently:

$$n - 1 = B(\sigma(n) - n),$$

which gives:

$$(\sigma(n) - n) \mid (n - 1).$$

> > Does it indeed work?

Comment: Thank you for the response , I hope what I wrote is correct. (mistakes are viewed with impatients)

Comment: @user128932, thank you for your feedback in the other MSE question as well.  At any rate, I think the direction

$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n)) = 1 \Longrightarrow (\sigma(n) - n) \mid (n - 1)$$

is the one that's true.  What I am not too sure about, is whether the reverse direction

$$(\sigma(n) - n) \mid (n - 1) \Longrightarrow \gcd(n,\sigma(n)) = 1$$

is also true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm not missing something.

If $\sigma(n)$ and $n$ had a common factor $d>1$, then we could write

$d(\sigma(n)/d-n/d)\mid n-1$, but $\gcd(d,n-1)=1$, a contradiction.

Edit:

In general for $k,a\in\Bbb Z^+$,
$$\sigma_k(n)-n^k\mid a\implies\gcd(\sigma_k(n),n^k)\mid a,$$
so if $a$ is coprime to $\sigma_k(n)$ or $n^k$, then they must be coprime to each other.